# So, i want to install Spotify but it wont let me, it is a dpkg error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, spotify

This is what it tells me anywhere I try, the store and terminal

```
*Setting up spotify-client (1:1.0.80.480.g51b03ac3-13) ...
dpkg: error processing package spotify-client (--configure):
 installed spotify-client package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 spotify-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*
```

So I want to know how to fix this and get this to work on my computer iv tried many things but nothing seems to work, i have also purged the Spotify client and reinstalled, and then it says the same thing
I need some help, my computer runs Deepin if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finn thank you, and snap installing doesn't work until you go to the store after snap installing it and put the client in through that and then it will install

This worked for me so i suggest it after you do it for anyone else with the problem, just follow these steps

1st- *if you dont have spotify already installed or tried and not working* do `sudo apt-get purge spotify-client`

2nd- do `sudo snap install Spotify`

3rd- *dont try to open Spotify yet* go to the store and download the current version of spotify when the snap is done, it will most likley error and just cancel it

4th- open the snap installed spotify, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try the snap version of spotify. Install it by running the follow command in Terminal:

```
sudo snap install spotify
```